# using javascript to read value from itemprop

Tags: javascript

Is it possible the read the price using the javascript

```
<span id="product_price_00873">
<span itemprop="price">178.00</span>
</span>
```

I just want to price 178.00. I can only using javascript.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

Use [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) as described in `icktoofay`'s answer, or perform the following:

```
const els = [...document.getElementsByTagName('span')];
props = els.filter(x => !!x.getAttribute('itemprop'));

// print the first element's price
console.log(props.shift().innerHTML)
```

---

**Original:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), i = 0, price;

for(i; i < els.length; i++) {
    prop = els[i].getAttribute('itemprop');

    if(prop) {
        price = els[i].innerHTML;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

If you have the product element in `product` and you're using a modern browser, this should work:

```
var price = product.querySelector('[itemprop=price]').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with complex websites and metadata is that meta tags not always have the **itemprop** attribute. And in some case they have **itemprop** only but not a **name** attribute.

With this script you can get all the Meta with an itemprop attribute and print its content.

```
  const allMeta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    
  for (let i = 0; i < allMeta .length; i++) {
      if( allMeta [i].getAttribute("itemprop") != null){
        console.log( allMeta [i].getAttribute("itemprop")+":"+allMeta [i].getAttribute('content') );
      }
  }
```