# how do I generate the values using plain JS from the span itemprop lines on this webpage?

Tags: javascript, microdata

I am trying to parse certain span tags from Winmo profiles (e.g., like https://open.winmo.com/open/decision_makers/ca/pasadena/jorge/garcia/489325) which do not have id or class values, i.e.,

```
<span itemprop="email">j****@***********.com</span>
<div itemscope="" itemprop="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">177 East West Colorado Boulevard</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Pasadena</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">91195</span>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>
```

I found two old StackOverflow examples helpful ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627756/using-javascript-to-read-value-from-itemprop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)), but I am still getting null values for each of the 9 span itemprop-matching lines on the webpage with the following code:

```
var nodes=[], values=[];
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), i = 0, whatev;
for(i; i < els.length; i++) {
    prop = els[i].getAttribute('itemprop');
    if(prop) {
        whatev = els[i];
        nodes.push(whatev.nodeName); // provides attribute names, in all CAPS = "SPAN"
        values.push(whatev.nodeValue); // for attribute values, why saying null if els[i] is fine?
        console.log(values); // (whatev) outputs whole thing, but it seems values is what I need
       // break; // need this? seems to prevent values after first span from generating
    }
}
```

How do I return just the partly-hidden email value (j****@***********.com) and the postalCode (91195) from these kinds of pages? I need the solution in plain JS because I will be compressing it into a bookmarklet for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the assignments from the itemprop attribute.

something like this:

```
function getItemPropsAsJSON(){
  var ob = {};
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(el=> {     
    var key = el.getAttribute('itemprop');
    var val = el.innerText;
    if (key && val) ob[key] = val;
  });
  return ob;
}
/* expected output: 
    {
      "name": "Jorge Garcia - Co-Founder & Chief Technology Officer, ICONIC | Contact Information, Email Address, Phone Number, Budgets and Responsibilities",
      "email": "j****@***********.com",
      "telephone": "(347) ***-****",
      "streetAddress": "177 East West Colorado Boulevard",
      "addressLocality": "Pasadena",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "91195",
      "addressCountry": "USA"
    }
*/
```

You may want to normalize the keys if you use this elsewhere, as the itemprop attributes may not always convert to the ideal object notation format. To do that, use the following:

```
function normalizeObjectNotation(key){
  return key && typeof key == 'string' && /[A-Z]/.test(key) && /\W+/.test(key) == false
  ? key.trim().split(/(?=[A-Z])/).reduce((a,b)=> a+'_'+b).replace(/^\d+/, '').toLowerCase() 
  : key && typeof key == 'string' ? key.trim().replace(/\W+/g, '_').replace(/^\d+/, '').toLowerCase() 
  : 'failed_object';
}

function getItemPropsAsJSON(){
  var ob = {};
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(el=> {     
    var key = el.getAttribute('itemprop');
    var val = el.innerText;
    if (key && val) ob[normalizeObjectNotation(key)] = val;
  });
  return ob;
}
getItemPropsAsJSON()

/* Expected Output:

{
  "name": "Jorge Garcia - Co-Founder & Chief Technology Officer, ICONIC | Contact Information, Email Address, Phone Number, Budgets and Responsibilities",
  "email": "j****@***********.com",
  "telephone": "(347) ***-****",
  "street_address": "177 East West Colorado Boulevard",
  "address_locality": "Pasadena",
  "address_region": "CA",
  "postal_code": "91195",
  "address_country": "USA"
}

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the flexible solution using JSON, and the normalizing tip, Andre. This and the other answer provided the same day were both excellent!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email span via the selector

```
span[itemprop="email"]
```

and the postalCode with the same method

```
span[itemprop="postalCode"]
```

With those selectors, use `querySelector` to get to the element, then extract its `textContent`:

```js
const [email, postalCode] = ['email', 'postalCode'].map(
  val => document.querySelector(`span[itemprop="${val}"]`).textContent
);
console.log(email);
console.log(postalCode);
```

```html
<span itemprop="email">j****@***********.com</span>
<div itemscope="" itemprop="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">177 East West Colorado Boulevard</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Pasadena</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">91195</span>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>
```

Comment: Excellent, efficient method! I didn't realize the array map method could be so elegantly applied to these non-standard span attributes/values.